# Sort a list of pointers to objects using lambda expression

Tags: c++, list, sorting, lambda

I am trying to sort a list of pointers to Pilot’s objects by the times they take to compete in a race. Times are computed through compete method in class Pilot. So I will be sorting them by a method rather than a class attribute.
Classes involved in the problem:

```
class Pilot
{
    double compete(Race *race); // Computes the time the pilot takes to finish the race
}
class Race
{
    list<Pilot*> pilots; // Pilots competing

    void sortByTime();
}
```

I want to sort the list using a lambda expression. Here is my try:

```
void Race::sortByTimes()
{ 
    sort(pilots.begin(), pilots.end(), [this](Pilot *p1, Pilot *p2) -> bool
    {
        return p1->compete(this) < p2->compete(this);
    });
}
```

I got 5 compile errors in algorithm library:

```
Error C2784 'unknown.type std::operator - (std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &, const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::move_iterator<_RantIt> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<PilotoOficial*>>>'
```

Two more C2784 errors in std:: reverse_iterator and std::_Revranit

```
Error C2676 binary : 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<Pilot*>>>' : does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Error C2780 'void std::_Sort(_RanIt,_RanIt,_Diff,_Pr' : expects 4 arguments; 3 provided
```

Comment: You do not need the `-> bool` after your lambda arguments

Answer (score 3):

Use [`std::list::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/sort). `std::sort` requires random-access iterators and you've given it bidirectional iterators. The other option would be to use a container like `std::vector` that has random-access iterators.